# Asynchronous Child Process in FastCGI Script

Tags: shell-script, background-process, fastcgi

Suppose that I want my server to sleep on any HTTP request to the path `/sleep` (i.e. `http://hostname/sleep`), but also send a complete response (`HTTP 200`) before sleeping.

[Using **nginx** with **FastCGI**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24690680/393280), I have configured the path in the **nginx** configuration:

```
location /sleep {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/path/to/fcgiwrap.socket;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/script.sh;
}
```

This invokes the following script (`/path/to/script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
cat << EOF
Content-Type: text/html

<html><head><title>Sleep</title><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body><p>Sleep: $(date)</p></body></html>
EOF
sleep 1 && sudo systemctl suspend < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Even though this will sleep the system, **FastCGI** will block until the child process completes, meaning that the web request will not complete before the system sleeps. So, how do I detach that final command from oversight by **FastCGI** so that the response completes, yet the command continues in the background, in this case ultimately to sleep the system?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether I use **nginx** or Apache, so I am not looking for an **nginx**-specific solution like setting the request timeout shorter than the script wait time (i.e. `sleep 5` in the script, but kill the request after 2 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decouple the cgi and the suspend by interposing a file used as a systemd trigger. See `man systemd.path` for this path-based activation of a unit. It has the advantage of not needing to use sudo from the cgi.

Create a unit file `/etc/systemd/system/mycgitrigger.path`

```
[Path]
PathModified=/some/writeable/file
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enable it.
Change the cgi script to simply write anything into the file `/some/writeable/file` in order to trigger the shutdown. Put the short timeout and shutdown command in a unit file
`/etc/systemd/system/mycgitrigger.service` (which does not need to be enabled).

Comment: For people who have familiarity with Systemd, they probably don't need the obvious tip that to have this work immediately, before the next boot, you must start the `.path` Unit explicitly (`systemctl start mycgitrigger.path`).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be

```
echo "sleep 1 && sudo systemctl suspend" | at now
```